# How to animate a UIImageView background

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I've got a background image and I wan't to animate it, but I have no idea of how.

What should I do?

Comment: What kind of animation? Spinner? Sliding up and down? Rotating? Moving forward and backward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an UIImageView and set the animationImages property to an array of images. You can set the duration and call startAnimating.

[Apple docs UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: got it!! 
     `UIImageView *_backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:smoke] autorelease];
    _backgroundView.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:_backgroundView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"skyAnimated" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
    _backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(_backgroundView.frame.origin.x+100,
         _backgroundView.frame.origin.y - 1000,
         _backgroundView.frame.size.width,
         _backgroundView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];`